# Pinging a server using C#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I was trying to ping a server using the Ping class, but after like 10 times that the method returns true, I keep getting false(which means the server is down[?] and it isn't) Here's the method:

```
     public bool IsConnectedToInternet()
    {
            Ping p = new Ping();
            try
            {

                PingReply reply = p.Send("www.uic.co.il", 1000);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());    
            }
            return false;
    }

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsConnectedToInternet);


        }
    }
```

Why am I keep getting false after a while?
Thank you.

Comment: You exception handling is the worst I've seen in a long time. Don't catch that exception: http://blog.gauffin.org/2010/11/do-not-catch-that-exception/. And `IsConnectedToInternet` should be a method `CheckConnection()` and not a property.

Comment: Please consider moving this to a Method. Properties are expected to have no cost.

Comment: In your `Catch` clause, try `Catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message.toString())}` and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for you replies, I will fix that, @Baboon what do you mean by saying that properties are expected to have no cost?

Comment: Adding to everyone's comments. bool result = false isn't necessary, just return false.

Comment: @jgauffin Is that better? Look in the edit, I still get false

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're flooding the server with requests:

```
for (; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsConnectedToInternet);
}
```

will loop as fast as possible sending request after request.

If you are just coding a keep alive service or service status control then using a timer that pings every minute or even every 10 minutes should be good enough.

Additionally, as others have pointed out in their comments, you are abusing properties by doing the ping in the getter as the call can potentially take some time and property getters should really return, if not instantly then very quickly. A `CheckConnection()` method would have clearer intent.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't really understand what you are saying, you say that the timeout should be atleast 1 minute?

Comment: He is saying that you poll the server every 10ms if the ping takes that long. Hence flooding it.

Comment: @idish - no. You are calling the ping far too often. Use a timer to control when the ping happens.

Comment: He's saying move this function to a method, and dont blast the server using an infinite loop to see if its up.  You will probably be fine by increasing the timeout to 5000 and only pinging once.

Comment: @cgatian My target is not to ping the server once, I want to flood the server with requests(only for learning of course). I have to use infinite loop if I want the method to be called every 5000 ms no?

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote your code.

It will trigger an event called `ConnectionLost` if connection is lost and an event called `Connected` when it gets connected again.

```
public class NetworkStateMonitor
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    bool _wasConnected = false;

    public NetworkStateMonitor()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnPing, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    public bool CheckInternetConnection() 
    {
        bool result = false;
        Ping p = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = p.Send("www.uic.co.il", 1000);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                return true;
        catch (PingException) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void OnPing(object state)
    {
        var newState = CheckInternetConnection();
        if (!newState && _wasConnected)
            ConnectionLost(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        else if (newState && !_wasConnected)
            Connected(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        _wasConnected = newState;
    }

    public event EventHandler ConnectionLost = delegate{};
    public event EventHandler Connected = delegate{};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting effort in trying to help me, I don't really understand this code tho, did you create 2 events? would this code work for me?

Comment: Because the timeout is still 1000 ms, and how often do I have to call these methods?

Comment: The timeout is 1000ms, but the ***polling interval*** is 10 seconds. You spammed the server with your `for` loop.

Comment: I understand now, I tried your using your code but there's an error with the timer constructor, I can't put there these arguments, its only constructor is getting a "double interval"

Comment: I am sorry for asking too many questions in once, I'll accept your answer once I succeed tho.

Comment: Updated the code to use the correct constructor. I've not tested it (just written it in the answer)

Comment: I have the following errors in the creation of _timer: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.TimerCallback' Error 3 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'long'

Comment: There are problems in the timer constructor

Comment: the callback method was missing a parameter. The following constructor should be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For other stumbling across this page, this function would be better if it were rewritten to:

```
public bool CheckInternetConnection(string HostName) 
{
    bool result = false; // assume error
    try {
        Ping oPing = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = oPing.Send(HostName, 3000);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success){
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception E) {
        // Uncomment next line to see errors
        // MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now call using:

```
bool IsSuccessful = CheckInternetConnection("www.uic.co.il");
```